# Wine 4.0 successfully installed, but wine --version returns wine-3.7

Tags: wine, games

I have just installed the latest version of wine using:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

If I run it again, it tells me `winehq-stable is already the newest version (4.0~bionic)`.

But if I run `wine --version` or any of the variants(wine64, wineserver, etc) they're showing me that version is 3.7. Why would that happen? How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you asking how to verify if the --version string is correct? (It may be, it may not). Or are you asking how to file a bug if it's wrong?

Comment: My goal is to be able to use wine 4.0. So Im asking how to replace the old one with it, or just find some command I can use to launch it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you trying to install wine 4.0 on your ubuntu:
Add repo key:

```
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key && sudo apt-key add winehq.key
```

Add repo:

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
```

And install:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

After those steps wine --version will print the correct version.

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I did.
"sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable"
returns:
"winehq-stable is already the newest version (4.0~bionic)"

Comment: Try to remove it by:
sudo apt purge winehq-stable
Or even:
sudo apt purge wine*
Then try to check if you still have some wine in PATH. And if NO try to install wine again.